# Admob Native Ads Not showing in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to load Admob Native ads in my android app. But they are not showing. I am unable to understand the problem. Please go through the code below.

**Note: I am using Admob Native Ads with Ad size "280x132"**

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.radioaudio.motivationalaudios.MyYouTubePlayer">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/videoTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Arise, Awake and stop not till the truth is known - Radio Story | IIT Kanpur Radio"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5059726881726792/7013814664"
        ads:adSize="280x132">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java File**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_youtube_player);
        //Admob Ad
        NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("A5E3E2068BD88202CBC281AD76984BEE")
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
    }
```

Comment: please share your logs as well. filter for Ads

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

Native ads takes time to show. So kindly wait for 2-3 hours. They will pop up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Add more logs here,so we can understand. Try to close and open your app again after some time. If it doesn't solve may be logs can help us out.

Additionally for your info, we can't display ads when we have YouTube player view in our layout. That's what you have. It's one of the issue that I've faced while publishing my app on play store.

It's kinda two way monetize:
1. In player video will display ads
2. Display banner/native ads at same time

That's what not allowed from Google side.

May be that can also be an issue, ads are not displayed. 
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can never show ad along with youtube or any services belong to google on the same page.